# Regex select all C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have:

```
<div class="content-text view-item-long-description-content">
        Yellow Taxi Magnetic Base Roof Top Cab LED Logga ljus med cigarett&#228;ndare 12V<br />
 <br />
 Helt ny!!!<br />
 Material: H&#246;g kvalitet PVC<br />
 Magnetisk bas (Easy f&#228;sta p&#229; taket)<br />
 F&#228;rg: Gul (Vitt &#228;r ocks&#229; tillg&#228;ngliga.)<br />
 LED-ljus F&#228;rg: Gul<br />
 Antal: 1 st<br />

</div>
```

I want select everything between `view-item-long-description-content">` and `</div>`.

I try:

```
Regex Allb = new Regex(@"content-text\s*view-item-long-description-content"">(.+?)</div>");
```

How I can select everything?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, "view-item-long-description-content\">(?'content'.*)<\\/div>");
if (match.Success)
{
   string content = match.Groups["content"].Value;
   // content is the whole block inside those two strings
}
else 
{
   // There was no match
}
```